# Unable to change value of an element in array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, element

Here's the code:

*HTML:*

```
<div id="ID1">
    <a href="www.google.com">click</a>
</div>
<a href="www.yahoo.com">click</a>
```

*JS:*

```
var element = document.querySelector("a[href^='www.google.com']");
console.log(element); // this returns the <a> object
element = element.parentNode;
console.log(element); // this returns the <div> object
```

worked perfect. But, here's the second part:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("a[href^='www.google.com']");
console.log(elements[0]); //this returns <a> object
elements[0] = elements[0].parentNode;
console.log(elements[0]); //this returns <a> instead of <div>
```

So, I couldn't change the value at `elements[0]`. Why this is happening? How can I change it without using `temp` variable like `temp = elements[0]; temp = temp.parentNode; console.log(temp);`?

Comment: Can't you use class and id for jquery selectors?

Comment: @Stages That would work though, but I'm curious to know why this fails in VanillaJS.

Comment: @gurvinder372 No, again it won't work. Try second part of code separately.

Comment: what does elements[1] give?

Comment: `elements[1]` also refuses to change. It stays with the `<a href="www.yahoo.com">click</a>` tag.

Comment: `var elements = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("a[href^='www.google.com']"))`

Comment: You can not alter the HTML collection.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko That worked. But, it is like copying and appending the elements NodeList, right? It looks similar to the `temp` case. Any idea about why the code fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`querySelectorAll` returns [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) not an `Array`. If you need to mutate it further convert it to array

```
var elements = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("a[href^='www.google.com']"))

elements[0] = elements[0].parentNode;
console.log(elements[0]); //div
```

The "funny" part is: the readonly behaviour is not crossbrowser.

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(document.querySelectorAll('a'), '0')
```

**Chrome**
**UPD** Chrome is lying about NodeList property. It is readonly and enumerable.

```
// {value: a, writable: true, enumerable: false, configurable: true}
```

**FF**

```
// { value: <a>, writable: false, enumerable: true, configurable: true }
```

**IE - who cares?**
IE is telling truth. Properties are writable.

```
// {configurable: true, enumerable: true, value: HTMLAnchorElement {...}, writable: true}
```

Comment: This answer is helpful, thanks. But, do you say that the [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) is writable for Chrome? I can't edit `document.querySelectorAll` [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) in both Chrome and Firefox. But, can edit them after conversion to array using `[].slice` in both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Yep, It seems Chrome is desperatelly lying about NodeList properties. Not only it is readonly it must be enumerable as well.

Comment: Okay. And, again back to the question, the first part code returns a Node, right? I didn't convert it to array. How it is writable? where NodeList in second part code is non-writable?

Comment: Well, the cases are totally different. When using `querySelector` you are simply assigning to variable `element` a new value. You are not writing to a property. When using `querySelectorAll` you are mutating the value itself by modifying its properties.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like as per [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)

> In other cases, the NodeList is a static collection, meaning any
>   subsequent change in the DOM does not affect the content of the
>   collection. document.querySelectorAll returns a static NodeList.

Strangely enough, assigning new values to any index doesn't change the values unless you do

```
elements = [].slice.call(elements);
elements[0] = elements[0].parentNode;
console.log(elements[0]); //this returns <a> instead of <div>
```

Now, it returns the value you are looking for.